# How to use gestureListener kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gesturelistener

i am trying to create a video player app using kotlin , now in player activity i am trying to use gesture listner but problem is i use a java class to use gesture listener , but in java onTouchListerner function
gesture listener class work somthly but in kotlin i dont know how to imple ment this class please help me

**OnSwifelistener.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public abstract class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
    private final GestureListener gestureListener;


    protected OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context){
        gestureListener = new GestureListener();
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestureListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gestureListener.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onSwipeRight() {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean onSwipeTop() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTap() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onSingleTap() {
        return true;
    }
    public abstract void onGestureDone();
    public abstract void adjustBrightness(double adjustPercent);
    public abstract void adjustVolumeLevel(double adjustPercent);
    public abstract void adjustVideoPosition(double adjustPercent, boolean forwardDirection);
    public abstract Rect viewRect();

    private enum SwipeEventType {
        NONE,
        BRIGHTNESS,
        VOLUME,
        SEEK,
        COMMENTS,
        DESCRIPTION
    }


    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
        private SwipeEventType swipeEventType = SwipeEventType.NONE;
        private MotionEvent startEvent;

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return OnSwipeTouchListener.this.onDoubleTap();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return onSingleTap();
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent end,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            // function depends on start position. (volume or brightness or play position.)
            double yDistance = end.getY() - start.getY();
            double xDistance = end.getX() - start.getX();

            if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.COMMENTS) {
                return onSwipeLeft();
            } else if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.DESCRIPTION) {
                return onSwipeTop();
            } else if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.BRIGHTNESS) {
                // use half of BrightnessRect's height to calculate percent.
                double percent = yDistance / (getBrightnessRect().height() / 2.0f) * -1.0f;
                adjustBrightness(percent);
            } else if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.VOLUME) {
                // use half of volumeRect's height to calculate percent.
                double percent = yDistance / (getVolumeRect().height() / 2.0f) * -1.0f;
                adjustVolumeLevel(percent);
            } else if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.SEEK) {
                double percent = xDistance / viewRect().width();
                adjustVideoPosition(percent, distanceX < 0);
            }

            return true;
        }

        private boolean isEventValid(MotionEvent event) {
            // this gesture just worked on single pointer.
            return event.getPointerCount() == 1;
        }

        private void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (isEventValid(event)) {
                // decide which process is needed.
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (swipeEventType == SwipeEventType.NONE && startEvent != null) {
                            swipeEventType = whatTypeIsIt(startEvent, event);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        onGestureDone();
                        swipeEventType = SwipeEventType.NONE;
                        startEvent = null;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }


        /**
         * Ok, swipe detected. What did user want? Let's find out
         */
        private SwipeEventType whatTypeIsIt(MotionEvent startEvent, MotionEvent currentEvent) {
            float startX = startEvent.getX();
            float startY = startEvent.getY();
            float currentX = currentEvent.getX();
            float currentY = currentEvent.getY();
            float diffY = startY - currentY;
            float diffX = startX - currentX;

            if (Math.abs(currentX - startX) >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(currentX - startX) > Math.abs(currentY - startY)) {
                if (getCommentsRect().contains((int) startX, (int) startY) && diffX > 0)
                    return SwipeEventType.COMMENTS;

                return SwipeEventType.SEEK;
            } else if (Math.abs(currentY - startY) >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                if (getDescriptionRect().contains((int) startX, (int) startY) && diffY > 0) {
                    return SwipeEventType.DESCRIPTION;
                } else if (getBrightnessRect().contains((int) startX, (int) startY)) {
                    return SwipeEventType.BRIGHTNESS;
                } else if (getVolumeRect().contains((int) startX, (int) startY)) {
                    return SwipeEventType.VOLUME;
                }
            }
            return SwipeEventType.NONE;
        }


        /**
         * Here we decide in what place of the screen user should swipe to get a new brightness value.
         */
        private Rect getBrightnessRect() {
            return new Rect(viewRect().right / 2, 0, viewRect().right, viewRect().bottom);
        }


        /**
         * Here we decide in what place of the screen user should swipe to get a new volume value.
         */
        private Rect getVolumeRect() {
            return new Rect(0, 0, viewRect().right / 2, viewRect().bottom);
        }


        /**
         * Here we choose a rect for swipe which then will be used to open the comments view.
         */
        private Rect getCommentsRect() {
            // 20% from right side will trigger comments view
            return new Rect((int)(viewRect().right - Math.min(viewRect().bottom, viewRect().right) * 0.2), 0, viewRect().right, viewRect().bottom);
        }

        /**
         * Here we choose a rect for swipe which then will be used to open the description view.
         */
        private Rect getDescriptionRect() {
            // 20% from bottom side will trigger description view
            return new Rect(0, (int)(viewRect().bottom - Math.min(viewRect().bottom, viewRect().right) * 0.2), viewRect().right, viewRect().bottom);
        }

    }

}
```

**and this is my kotlin relative layout ontouchlistener code**

```
binding.playerView.setOnTouchListener(OnSwifeListener)
```

How to implement above java class in kotlin touch listener?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can use the android studio "Convert java file to kotlin" functionality and start from there.

Comment: [This will help you.](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/GestureDetector)